# WPF: On-screen validation

Tags: wpf, validation

What technique or library do you recommend for on-screen validation. That is, validation that is very visible to the user.

My requirements:

1. The validation must have a way to indicate to the user which fields have a problem.
2. The validation must have a way to indicate to the user how to fix the problem.
3. The validation must support comparatives like TextboxA > Textbox B.
4. The validation must support custom logic like "If CheckBoxC is checked, ListBoxD must be empty".
5. Sometimes, though not always, the user can save a record even though validation fails.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of using IDataErrorInfo and ValidationRules should meet all of your criteria.

1 & 2 - can be handled easily using the standard WPF validation display techniques.  For background info, I'd read [Josh Smith's MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx#id0190106), in particular, he shows a couple of ways to handle displaying validation information.

3 & 4 - can be handled easily via [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx). This interface lets you do any logic required in order to display validation, and can combine multiple properties in the validation rules.

5 - This is a matter of just tracking which rules prevent saving, and which do not.  You'll need to handle this directly, but again, IDataErrorInfo can help here, since you can use a known set that allow saving, and have every other issue prevent it.

For simple cases, Validation Rules make life easy.  [They can be combined with IDataErrorInfo](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/combinding-wpf-validation-rules-and-idataerrorinfo-to-validate-conversion-errors), however, for a nice mix of simple with extended logic for difficult cases.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds really promising.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the **BookLibrary** and **EmailClient** sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** interesting. They use the IDataErrorInfo interface in combination with the .NET DataAnnotations attributes to define the validation rules.